# How to query posts from specific authors and categories using WP_query?

Tags: categories, wp-query, taxonomy, multi-author

I currently have a WP_query where I am getting posts from a specific set of authors. To this, I want to add specific categories as well.

```
$args = array( 'author__in' => $authors, 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'paged' => $paged );
```

$authors is an array containing users' ids.

So, I need to query posts from both, authors and categories.

I was thinking about using something like this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => array ( $cat_ids ),
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy', => 'user',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => array( $user_ids ),
    )
)
```

I know user is not a taxonomy; however, I am looking for something similar that works.

### EDIT

Well, I tried this and it is working so far:

```
$args = array(
  'author__in'     => $authors,
  'category__in'   => $terms,
  'posts_per_page' => 12,
  'paged'          => $paged
);
```

Is there a better way?

### EDIT 2

My previous edit is not working the way I wanted. The caveat is that when only categories are specified, no posts show up.
I need an OR relation.

### EDIT 3

I havent been able to find a solution. When I use author_*in and category*_in for the arguments, wordpress only shows posts from authors and not both. I need to show posts from authors AND categories. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `author__in` is the way to do it, but that looks like what you started with.

Comment: yes, but now I want to get the posts from specific categories as well in the same query.

Comment: [There is very limited user search capability to `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters). Sorry. It is not clear what you want. There are multiple ways to interpret your question. Please enumerate your conditions very carefully.

Comment: ok, let me try to clear it up. I want to query posts based on categories and authors ids in the same query.

Comment: hi, are you working with post type "post"? and taxonomy "category"?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$query = new wp_query($arr);
    $arr = array(
        'author__in'=> array(2,4,6), //Authors's id's you like to include
        'posts_per_page' => '12',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => array ( $cat_ids ),
        )
    )
    );
```

Comment: Yes I was looking for something like that. I was not sure if I could keep author__in I am still learning and I want to do things the right way. My EDIT is also working, so what would you recommend me using?

Comment: Your edit seems good for me, as long as it fulfills the purpose.

Comment: What happens if there are no authors? Will posts from specified categories still show up?

Comment: Well, in that case posts will not show up. I guess WP_Query does logical AND with queries and if some parameter is not there it will end up with nothing.

What you can do is setup 2 queries, when query one fails (returns null) the other one (without the author parameter) picks up the path.

Comment: I havent found a solution for this. Where else can I look for help? When I use author__in and category__in inside the arguments, it only shows posts from authors, not categories.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this... [get_posts_by_author_sql](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts_by_author_sql)

Alternatively, if you want to select posts based on authors/categories you could use [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). You may be able to use a "JOIN" in the SQL to get the post IDs you need.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this in backend:

```
wp-admin/edit.php?author=2 //author is specified
wp-admin/edit.php?cat=16,25&author=2 //include categories
```

this test does not appear as you describe, so check whether the value is correct

```
$terms = array(16,25);
//$author = array(2);
$args = array(
    'author__in'  => isset($author) ? $author : 0,
    'category__in' => isset($terms) ? $terms : ''
    );
$demos = new WP_Query($args);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($demos);
echo "</pre>";
```